# Not getting token address

Tags: go-ethereum, erc-20

Hi i am trying to get already deployed token instance 
here is my code

```
async loadBlockchainData(){

  this.tokenAddress = 0xebee955631d342484bc4a0a2302b9273d48ecc6b;

  const tokenAbi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"delegate","type":"address"},{"name":"numTokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"totalSupply","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"name":"buyer","type":"address"},{"name":"numTokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"decimals","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"tokenOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"string"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"receiver","type":"address"},{"name":"numTokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transfer","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"owner","type":"address"},{"name":"delegate","type":"address"}],"name":"allowance","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"name":"total","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"tokenOwner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"spender","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"name":"tokens","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"}]

  const web3 = window.web3

  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()

  this.setState({account: accounts[0] })

  const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId()

  const networkData = NeutralG.networks[networkId]

  console.log(networkId)

  if (networkData) {
    const token = web3.eth.Contract(tokenAbi,this.tokenAddress)


    console.log(token.address)
  }
  else{
    window.alert('NeutralG contract not deployed to detected network.')
  }

}
```

I am printing the address and getting 
`1.346933417561969e+48` this value instead of an address where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the type of `0xebee955631d342484bc4a0a2302b9273d48ecc6b` is `Number`, yet its value is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, which is 53 bits long.

Solidity `address` types are 160 bits long, and they are passed to and from web3.js functions as strings; so to begin with, change `0xeb...6b` to `"0xeb...6b"`.

---

Second, change `web3.eth.Contract` to:

- `web3.eth.contract` if you're using web3.js v0.x
- `new web3.eth.Contract` if you're using web3.js v1.x

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
this.tokenAddress = "0xebee955631d342484bc4a0a2302b9273d48ecc6b";
```

That's the conventional way to pass an address.